# Display Array<Object> in PrimeNg template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng, angular-datatables

I have this kind of JSON:

```
    {
       description: "Some Description",
       child: [{
          description2: "Some Other Description",
          description3: "Another Description"
       }]

    }
```

And I want to display it on my PrimeNg DataTable, but somehow it always show blank cell.

Here is my column code

```
    <p-column field="child" header="Child">
      <ng-template let-col let-item="rowData" pTemplate="body" >
        <tr ngFor="let child of item.child">
          <td>
            {{child.description2}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my solution after some trials, here is my answer:

```
    <p-column>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">Child</ng-template>
      <ng-template let-col let-childs="rowData.child" pTemplate="body" >
        <tr *ngFor="let child of childs">
          <td>{{child.description2}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```